# Aristotelian physics

Tags: science-based, outdated-science

Would

- Aristotelian natural philosophy, with planets and Sun orbiting the Earth, and forces needed to maintain motion
- Things having natural places and desiring to reach it
- *horror vacui*
- Four elements

build an usable base for a fantasy world?

Comment: If you write a world which does justice to his concept of entelechia, i want to read it!

Comment: I think this is a duplicate, with an answer that posts a reference to a novel that does exactly that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Worldbuilding in science-fiction or fantasy will always make assumptions about the nature of their fictional worlds. The usual criteria is that logical consistency is maintained for the duration of the story. Science-based SF will attempt to keep the science congruent with current scientific understanding even though such stories will often have elements of speculative or imaginary science.

Aristotelian physics can provide a speculative basis for an imagined world. Admittedly by current standards, it contradicts our understanding of the cosmos. However, a lot of fiction still peddles concepts and tropes that are contrary to current science. Bad old ideas can take time to flush out of the system of conventional thinking.

There is an argument that SF still hangs on to the Newtonian worldview, and is only slowly coming to grips with cosmos run by quantum mechanics and relativity. Using Aristotelian physics is a perfectly plausible conceptual framework to construct a fantasy world.

Side-note: Science itself doesn't have a set of complete theories to explain the cosmos whole and entire. Every piece worldbuilding, especially in SF, that sticks to close to current science will sooner or later become outmoded and outdated. Outmoded science is full of wonderful concepts like phlogiston, the luminiferous ether and polywater. They deserve the right to star in their own fantasy worlds.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Absolutely. In fact, it's probably already been done before.

The four elements are often used as a basis for magic in many worlds, and there's no reason to suppose that you couldn't give a more logical explanation for magic's existence based upon Aristotelian logic.

If I were you designing a world with magic, I'd focus most of my attention onto the four elements. If you want to get into Plato's work, you could explain a fire as simply tetrahedrons, or the oceans as many icosahedrons. This would be able to logically explain magic (a fireball is simply the creation and movement of tetrahedrons) in a fantasy universe where it exsts.

If it's more of a science-fiction-y type fantasy world, I'd put more emphasis onto the solar system aspect of his works. Having everything orbit the Earth makes it the centre of the solar system, and an immediate target for any type of invader.

*Horror Vacui* seems like a harder topic to make use of, but I suppose that you could use it quite literally in any world with sentient plants. If *Nature abhors a vacuum*, the plants could want to conquer the world, as any space where they are not present may be considered a vacuum?

OK, that just sounds dumb now I'm re-reading it.

Comment: By nature it doesn't just mean vegetation. It is simply the Aristotelian concept that in the universe there is no such thing as nothingness (which Aristotle "proves" with faulty logic). As soon as a vacuum forms, "nature" or rather natural laws, would according to the idea, ensure something would fill it. Plants certainly wouldn't conquer the world as clearly the earth is filled with earth, water, fire and air. Even the skies beyond the earth (what we would call space) is not empty as it is occupied by Aether.

Comment: @AngelPray Yeah, I know. That was my brain just whirring without consideration to what it was actually saying. I understand that _Horror Vacui_ means that the natural laws of the universe will always fill a void as soon as it forms, and that the fifth Classical Element Aether fills space, but as I say, thought without thinking.

Answer (score 0):

For a primitive understanding of physics in a fantasy world, surely; after all, it did perform that function on Earth for about 19 centuries.

The problem with pre-Newtonian physics is that the only parts which allowed actual calculation of effects were kinematics and statics, neither of which is affected by the silly theories of *impetus* etc. Pre-newtonian physics simply had *no quantitative understanding of dynamics* at all, much less of electromagnetism. That is to say, pre-Newtonian dynamics was essentially *pure handwaving*, there were no numbers in there at all.

Comment: I don't want a world where people simply believe in peripatetic dynamics, (this way Medieval Era would do the job. ) I want arrows be really propelled by the air surrounding them and having virtus movens. (Instead of having impulse.)

Comment: @b.Lorenz: The big problem is that pre-newtonian physics simply did not have any quantitative theory of dynamics. None. It's not that it was incorrect -- it simply did not exist. It was all words, technobabble. No quantitative relationships whatsoever. Statics, yes, they did fine, long live the memory of Archimedes. Kinematics, yes, because it is just geometry.

Comment: I've read, although maybe incorrect, that the commentators of Aristotele made up the formula v=F/R, (of course not with the modern notation) where R is supposed to mean some 'resistance' caused by the medium, the moving object is traveling in.

Comment: See how vague is the reasoning in the [theory of impetus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theory_of_impetus), the high-mark of pre-galilean / pre-newtonian dynamics. What they _could_ measure were forces, positions and speeds; what they lacked was a relationship linking forces and movements. So if you really want a world with Aristotelian mechanics you must make up your own relationships.

Comment: So they lacked the concept of acceleration?

Comment: No, they did, although measuring it was something else. They had good understanding of kinematics grace to the work of mathematicians -- kinematics is pure geometry. In the Antiquity and the Middle Ages they just did not have much use for dynamics -- machines were few, most of them could be calculated well enough using statics alone, they had no precise timepieces anyway, artillery was feeble etc.

Comment: They knew the acceleration, but failed to connect it with force and mass?

Comment: What they really lacked was an understanding of _inertia_. Galieo's and Newton's big breakthrough in mechanics is the first law of motion.